# ontap in gesture detector flutter

Tags: python, java, flutter, dart

ontap in the gesture detector in my code below  is not work for me.

```
 return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:  const Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Row(
            children: [
               Expanded(
                child:  GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                    selectedGender = Gender.male;
                    });
                  },
                  child:  ReusableCard(
                      selectedGender == Gender.male? activeColor:inactiveColor,
                    const IconContent(FontAwesomeIcons.mars,"MALE")
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I try to tap the maleCard then the color is not changed to active
it is not work as I expect please any one can help me

Comment: Can you include more about `ReusableCard`

Answer (score 0):

Every time onTap clicked selectedGender is getting the same value and that's why its not changing the color

```
 setState(() {
            selectedGender = Gender.male;
          });
```

At above selected Gender value is always Gender.Male
You can do it like this

```
 setState(() {
(selectedGender==Gender.male)?(selectedGender=Gender.female):(selectedGender=Gender.male)
                });
```

In changed code when you click on tap then first it will check the value of selectedFender and if its value is male then it will changed into female and vice versa